# when exposure time is longer, the Poisson noise become Gaussian

Tags: noise, gaussian

Can we have an explanation of why exposure time is longer, the Poisson noise become Gaussian?

Or any reference? Please provide a reference and I like to dig into more.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by exposure?

Comment: And check this out btw

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: Assuming you are counting particles, e.g., photons, for some exposure time (integration period), and assuming Poisson statistics, then the mean is the product of arrival rate and exposure time. This is also the variance, so SNR, defined as mean/standard deviation, increases if arrival rate or exposure time increase. And the Poisson distribution becomes narrower, more symmetric and looks more like a discrete version of a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Ben said it correctly but  succinctly. To be slightly more detailed,  the reason why the approximation works is due to the CLT for the sum of iid rv's with finite variance. See this link for details.  https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/28/28.2